# angular ui.bootstrap - I'm trying to get a confirm dialog working (really any dialog at this point)

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-bootstrap

I'm looking [here](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/) at the $modal service. I'm trying to implement a confirm dialog when the user clicks a delete button...

Right now I've got:

```
'use strict';

angular.module('dashboard.build').controller('BuildCtrl', ['$scope', '$modal', 'BuildSrvc', function($scope, $modal, BuildSrvc) {
  BuildSrvc.refreshBuilds(function(builds) {
    $scope.builds = builds;
  });

  $scope.deployBuild = function(build) {
  }

  $scope.deleteBuild = function(build) {
    var modalInstance = $modal.open({
      templateUrl: 'html/buildDelete.html',
      controller: 'buildDeleteCtrl',
      resolve: {
        items: ['Delete', 'Cancel']
      }
    });

    modalInstance.result.then(function (selectedItem) {
      $scope.selected = selectedItem;
    }, function () {
      $log.info('Modal dismissed at: ' + new Date());
    });
  }
}]);


angular.module('dashboard.build').controller('buildDeleteCtrl', ['$scope', '$modalInstance', 'data', function($scope, $modalInstance, items) {
  $scope.items = items;
  $scope.selected = {
    item: $scope.items[0]
  };

  $scope.ok = function () {
    $modalInstance.close($scope.selected.item);
  };

  $scope.cancel = function () {
    $modalInstance.dismiss(null);
  };
}]);
```

When I try to click the delete button, the `$scope.deleteBuild` is called but I get an error: `Argument 'fn' is not a function, got string`. Not really sure whats going on as I'm still learning. any pointers on how to correct this?

Comment: Please try to put your code in plunker and post a live reproduce scenario.

Answer (score 1):

Inside of your modal resolve, you have:

```
  resolve: {
    items: ['Delete', 'Cancel']
  }
```

The 'items' expects a function to return successfully. This has to do with promises (probably), which I cannot explain at the moment, but to fix your bug try this:

```
resolve: {
    items: function () {
        return ['Delete','Cancel'];
    }
}
```